# Linux permissions are not respected

Tags: linux

I've run into a perplexing problem where user permissions are not being respected on a Linux computer. Other users are able to move and delete files they don't own. Is there a way to restrict this? Why is this happening? Here's an example.

```
# Become user jen
[root@localhost test]# su jen

# Display files in the current directory
[jen@localhost test]$ ls -al
total 24
drwxrwxrwx.  3 root root  4096 Apr 10 09:49 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 19 root root  4096 Apr  9 18:19 ..
drwx------.  2 root root 16384 Apr  9 16:15 lost+found

[jen@localhost test]$ touch jen_file
[jen@localhost test]$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jen jen     0 Apr 10 09:50 jen_file
drwx------. 2 root root 16384 Apr  9 16:15 lost+found

# Exit user jen and become user mike
[jen@localhost test]$ exit
[root@localhost test]# su mike

# Try to modify jen's file as mike. Permission denied, like normal.
[mike@localhost test]$ echo "test" > jen_file
bash: jen_file: Permission denied

# User mike can move jen's file! This should not happen.
[mike@localhost test]$ mv jen_file mike_file
[mike@localhost test]$ ls -l
total 16
-rw-rw-r--. 1 jen jen     0 Apr 10 09:50 mike_file
drwx------. 2 root root 16384 Apr  9 16:15 lost+found

# User mike can delete jen's file. This definately should not happen!
[mike@localhost test]$ rm -f mike_file
[mike@localhost test]$ ls -l
total 16
drwx------. 2 root root 16384 Apr  9 16:15 lost+found
```

Not sure if it's relevant, but here is the fstab line for the mounted partition (where this test is being run):

```
# Device name           Mount point   Type   Attributes                     Dump   Check
/dev/mapper/vg00-test   /test         ext4   defaults,acl,user_xattr,nodev  0      3
```

Comment: You can 'fix' this with `chmod o-rwx /home/jen` (which is currently set to d rwx rwx **rwx** .  3 root root  4096 Apr 10 09:49 .  (The rights relevant for Mike and everybody else are bolded). The real question here is how a directory in /home got that way, and how the rights are on the other home directories.

Comment: @Hennes: This would prevent jen from accessing the file as well, unless she is in the root group, as now she can't even `cd` into this directory.

Comment: @Hennes: Also, no one mentions `/home`, this is all happening on `/test`.

Comment: Good point on both of them. As to the first: I guess I am used to `su - username` which would also change the dir to ~jen. It took me a while to realise the dash was not present.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to check the ACL permissions?: # getfacl /home/jen

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, this is working as expected. The 'mv' consists of a read operation, which mike is allowed to do by the o+r, a write, which mike is allowed to do by o+rwx on the directory, and a delete, which mike is allowed to do by o+rwx on the directory. To get the behavior you're looking for, chmod the directory to mode 1777.

Comment: To add a bit of explanation: mode `1777` set the sticky bit, which restrict file system operations on a file to the owner of the file`.

Answer (score 4):

You are misunderstanding the permission concept.

Move and delete are operations on the directory, not on the file. And mike has read/write permission for the directory.